# Is there any possibility to check several attributes of element

Tags: java, selenium

I want to check several attributes of element (for example, is element displayed and that it's content is not empty) and I also want to know is there any simple way to this, because now I have code like this:

```
 result= adplace.findElement(By.xpath("../../..")).findElement(ADPL_CURRENT_STATUS).isDisplayed()
                   && !(adplace.findElement(By.xpath("../../..")).findElement(ADPL_CURRENT_STATUS).getAttribute("innerText").equals(""));
```

And I want something like this (this is obviously not working code):

```
 result= adplace.findElement(By.xpath("../../..")).findElement(ADPL_CURRENT_STATUS)
  .isDisplayed() && 
  .getAttribute("innerText").equals(""));
```

Is there any possibility to simplify my code?

Comment: You need to learn basic Java syntax, especially how to deal with variables.

Comment: @chrylis What do you mean? What I do wrong particularly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a `WebElement` variable and reuse, no need to find the element again:

```
WebElement elm = adplace.findElement(By.xpath("../../..")).findElement(ADPL_CURRENT_STATUS);
result = elm.isDisplayed() && (!elm.getText().equals(""));
```

Note that I've also replaced the `innerText` with `getText()` method call.

Comment: Thanks! I also wanted to avoid using additional variable for that, but it seems to be only reasonable way, as I see...